# Can a Keycloak Event Listener inject some value in the ftl? How?

Tags: keycloak

We're trying to make a Keycloak event listener feed some data into the next ftl running but we're unable to do it.

We've tried to set some attributes in several objects that are available in the event listeners but the only one we are able to read in the ftl is the ClientBean, which does not seem to be a good choice, since it's probably shared between several users at the same time. We've tried Session, User, which seemed the best options, but we get null when we use them in freemarker.

Does anybody know of an example of how to do this?